# How to calculate percentage of total in Wix using SPI AdditionalFees

Tags: javascript, string, percentage

I need to calculate a 3% processing fee to my Wix website upon checkout on the cart page. I’m relatively new to coding and followed the Velo SPI Additional Fee tutorial but it returns a set number instead of a percentage.

Then how do I take that percentage and multiply that by the total order to get a new grand total?

I followed the Velo SPI tutorial and the results added $3 to the order.

I need a calculation that would return a value of 3% of the order to be added as a separate cost.